# PHP MYSQL CREATE TABLE Issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What's wrong with the following code:

```
$table = $email . "Entries";
$query = "CREATE TABLE ".$table."(FirstName varchar(15),LastName varchar(15),Age int)";
```

I want to create a table whose name is dynamic based on a posted variable. The above doesn't work however. I have also tried:

```
$query = "CREATE TABLE $table(FirstName varchar(15),LastName varchar(15),Age int)";
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: What error are you getting? Use `mysql_error()` to see what error MySQL is returning.

Comment: make sure to catch if ur trying to create tables with the same name

Comment: The method you are using look as though it is wide open to SQL injection. Are you escaping `$email` before using it? Is it really necessary to create a table from a posted value, or could another more secure method be used?

Comment: Any reason you're creating a table to store what would seem to be just one record? Why not a single table with `email,FirstName,LastName,Age` fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot find the relevant documentation, but would assume that if `$email` contains an `@` this would be an invalid table name in MySQL.

```
CREATE TABLE email@example.comEntries (FirstName varchar(15),LastName varchar(15),Age int)
```

If this is the case, try enclosing the table name in backticks:

```
$query = "CREATE TABLE `$table` (FirstName varchar(15),LastName varchar(15),Age int)";
```

Comment: Or a space or any number of other invalid characters. @user559142 - what sort of validation are you performing on the input?

Comment: [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html) you were referring to. @ is only valid in backticks.

Comment: @cularis Thank you.  I was searching for "identifiers" rather than "object names"

Answer (score 0):

$query = "CREATE TABLE $table(FirstName varchar(15),LastName varchar(15),Age int)";
I am not too sure if you can have "@" in the name of a table....